# Does $A \succeq B A^{-1} B$ imply that $A \succeq B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B$ be two symmetric matrices with equal dimensions. Suppose $A \succeq 0 $ (ie, PSD), $B \succeq 0$ and $$ A - B A^{-1} B \succeq 0.$$ Then is it true that $A-B \succeq 0 $?

Comment: I think the best conclusion to get from this is that $M=B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}$ satisfies $M\succeq M^{-1}$, so all eigenvalues of $M$ are at least $1$.

Comment: I am trying to follow, but got stuck on the first step. Where does the $M$ come from (and why does $M\succeq I$ imply $A\succeq B$)?

Comment: see my latest edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. We have
$$
M=B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}\succeq I \implies A \succeq B
$$
*Note: we need that $M\succeq M^{-1}$ and $M \succeq 0$ to conclude that $M \succeq I$.*

---

To clarify:
$$
A - BA^{-1}B \succeq 0 \implies\\
A \succeq BA^{-1}B \implies\\
B^{-1/2} A B^{-1/2} \succeq B^{1/2} A^{-1} B^{1/2} \implies\\
M \succeq M^{-1} (\text{where } M = B^{-1/2} A B^{-1/2}) \implies\\
M^2 \succeq I
$$
Now, $M$ is a positive semidefinite matrix with $M^2 \succeq I$.  Conclude that $M \succeq I$. Finally, we have
$$
B^{-1/2} A B^{-1/2} \succeq I \implies
A \succeq B^{1/2}B^{1/2} = B
$$ 
which is what we wanted.

Comment: thanks for the clarify, that's helpful. Just another small question. Why do we know that pre/postmultiplying by $B^{-1/2}$ and by $M$ preserves psd here?

Comment: $M^2 = M^{1/2}MM^{1/2}$

Comment: In general, if $A$ is symmetric and psd, then so is $PAP^T$ for any matrix $P$.

Comment: ah, great! I was previously trying to show that at each multiplication step the two factors commute, but that's much easier. thanks!